# Trying to parse csv file where some COLUMN cells are empty

Tags: java, string, csv, parsing, java.util.scanner

**I am trying to read a .csv file which has 6 columns, but some rows in the last column is empty cell.**

```
item1   2   4   125 200 
item2   5   8   250 375 
item3   2   3   125 200 
item4   2   4   200 325 10
item5   1   2   325 400 10
item6   1   2   250 350 10
```

Result

```
row 0: item1
row 1: 2.0
row 2: 4.0
row 3: 125.0
row 4: 200.0
new --------: 0
row 0: item2
row 1: 5.0
row 2: 8.0
row 3: 250.0
row 4: 375.0
new --------: 0
row 0: item3
row 1: 2.0
row 2: 3.0
row 3: 125.0
row 4: 200.0
```

> - Java code should get all the rows, parse each value into double.
> - The last column if its empty, print a 0 value, otherwise parse the    last    column value

**QUESTION: How to i get empty cell value for rows and set int lastColEmpytyValue = 0;?**

```
    while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
    String data = inputStream.nextLine(); // gets a while line .next gets next word i.e. ice. .nextLine get word with spaces i.e. ice cream

        String[] row = data.split(",", -1); // regex - split line

    System.out.println("row 0: " + row[0] ); 
    System.out.println("row 1: " + Double.parseDouble(row[1] )); 
    System.out.println("row 2: " + Double.parseDouble(row[2]) ); 
    System.out.println("row 3: " + Double.parseDouble(row[3]) ); 
    System.out.println("row 4: " + Double.parseDouble(row[4]) ); 
    if (row[5] == null || row[5].isEmpty() || row[5] == "") {
        int row5;
        row[5] = "0";
        row5 = Integer.parseInt(row[5]);
        System.out.println("new --------: " +row5);

    } else {
        System.out.println("row 5.....: " + row[5]);

    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: fixed. updated q

Comment: I do not see any data separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just change the line, because I don't see ',' in your example data.

```
String[] row = data.split(",", -1);
```

to something like if you data has tab or space as separator.

```
//if you have "tabbed" separated data
String[] row = data.split("\t", -1);   
// if you have "space" separated data
//String[] row = data.split(" ", -1);
```

Comment: The issue with using an API is I am restricted to use it is I have to update class path.. I assume this would be required for csv?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't "get empty cell value" when there is no value. The `split` function will return only as many elements as exist in the string. So, in the case where there are only 5 values, it will return an array of length 5 (subscripts 0 through 4). And yet you are unconditionally trying to access position 5 in the array (in the `if` statement).

Instead, you should check the `length` of the array first, and if it's less than 5 then use 0 for the value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an external library to handle this for you reliably?
If you can try [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it's easy and way faster:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically();
settings.setNullValue("0"); //if a value is null, convert it to 0

//always reads the first 6 columns
//you won't need this if the shorter rows with no data end with a tab
parserSettings.selectIndexes(0,1,2,3,4,5);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
//parse into Records as you can get primitive types from them.
List<Record> record = parser.parseAllRecords(file);
```

Hope this helps.
Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free.